# How to call member function inside a member function without static?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, methods

i tried to solve my problem for several days now but i am stuck and i hope you can help me.

I am trying to use the method `void start(CallbackFunction callback){}` inside a library i imported in my C++ Project. That method wants another method which i created in my custom class `MyClass` named `static void my_callback(const Param& param){}`. The method i want to use in my `main()` is `static void my_function()`.

So the procedure is `main() -> my_function() -> start(my_callback());` (as shown in the main() below)

The code i attached works perfectly fine. **The problem is i have to declare everything static to make it work and i really do not want that.** I hope there is a possiblity to remove the static.

**Also i am NOT able to change anything in LibClass, the param struct or the typedef.**

Here is my working code so far:

```
#include <functional>

struct Param {
    float progress;
    uint16_t index;
};

typedef void(*CallbackFunction)(const Param& param);

class LibClass {
public:
    LibClass(){}
    void start(CallbackFunction callback){}
};

class MyClass {
public:
    //LibClass libClass;

    static void my_function() { // <-- how do i do this without static
        LibClass libClass; // <-- this should be a non-static class variable
    
        libClass.start(my_callback); // <-- how to write this line then
    
    }

    static void my_callback(const Param& param) { // <-- how do i do this without static
    
    }
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.my_function();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::function` and a lambda expression for `myCallback`, rather than making it a `static` class member function. We could help you better, if you'd bother to explain what's your real use case for doing that. Usually if you have member functions (non `static`) you can just call, them. If you wan't to keep it static, you'll have to pass `this` as parameter there, that any class instance level members can be accessed there.

Comment: Which parts do you and don't you have control over? Are you the one that defines `LibClass`? Does `CallbackFunction` have to have this specific signature? It's surprising that an apparently C++ library uses C-style callback mechanism.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik as i said in my question CallbackFunction, LibClass and the Param struct sadly have to stay like this. Everything else can be modified. The real use case is controlling LEDs with the help of the mentioned library which only provides this class/method.

Comment: Then you are stuck, I'm afraid. The library you use doesn't provide any way to dispatch a callback to a non-static member function (short of, say, storing `MyClass` pointer in a global variable).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If i had control over the library and so on, could you show me an example what exactly i had to change to make it work without static and my own class ? That would be at least helpful for my understanding. Thank you for your time anyway

Comment: Well, a fully C++ library could have taken, say, `std::function<void(const Param& param)>` as a callback. Then you could do `libClass.start([this](const Param& param) { my_callback(param);})` , and `my_callback` could be non-static. A C-style library often takes a `void*` pointer alongside the callback, and passes it back to the callback unchanged. This way you can pass a `this` pointer to the callback - this still requires a static function (sometimes called a "trampoline"), which can simply call a non-static function where real work is performed.

Comment: Somehow sad that the library is the problem so i am not able to programm as i would like to but at least i know the problem now. Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

`LibClass`'s interface only handles function pointer (without user data), so you won't be able to pass instance cleanly.

For the remaining part, you might get rid of some `static`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    LibClass libClass;

    void my_function() { libClass.start(my_callback); }

    static void my_callback(const Param& param) { // static need here, of free function
        // ...
    }
};

int main ()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.my_function();
}
```